# Amount of matter in two infinite universes

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, matter

I don't know exactly where to find any other information on this question so I thought I would ask here. If there were two infinitely large universes one where 20% of the space in the universe was taken by matter and nothing else and one with 30% of its space taken up by matter and nothing else would you be able tell the difference of matter percentage between the universes or would they seem to have the same amount.

Comment: If there was no way of distinguishing the two, how would you know they were different to begin with?

Comment: Re my answer to your question, I'd edit your question myself (which is permitted on PSE, but costs points if the edit's rejected), except that I have no idea what cosmological models you might be talking about.  (Their proportions of mass seem kind of large.)  If you're interested in how infinity affects physics, the concept of it seems like kind of a last resort when all observations, experiments, and other inferences have failed, as discussed by the physicist Sabine Hossenfelder at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bq9xR5PUs6s .

Comment: The proportions of mass might not be too large if you accept the extremely dense false vacuum of field-based inflation, but I prefer the inflation or "black hole genesis" advanced by Smolin, and detailed in 2010-2020 papers, available free on Arxiv,  by Nikodem J. Poplawski.  (Being a procrastinator, I prefer multiverses with no beginning.)

Answer (score 1):

Because percentages are dimensionless numbers (each representing only a portion of the particular object of which it is a percentage), they are not what the mathematician Cantor (extremely important in astronomy and cosmology) called "countably infinite":  As a result, the information you may be seeking, which I'd imagine might be a comparison of their sizes, cannot be elaborated from the information that you've provided about the universes concerned.  (The comparison, from the specific information that you've provided so far, would simply be that both universes would be infinite.)

You might edit your question to make it more specific.